# Validate with "List from a range" only if another cell is not empty on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I would like to use validation "List from a range" in all the cells of column B only if in the correspondent cell in column A there is data in it.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

List from a range option of data validation doesn't work that way. You could try to use a custom formula, but this option doesn't show a dropdown.

Comment: do you think that can be possible with Google Script instead?